# Are there any form builder tools written in rails, any gems or plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Looking for something that non programmers could drag and drop and create entities and forms to do simple business processes. Seems like it wouldn't be that hard, but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

To be clear I am looking for something that gives the power to the user of the app to build forms and entities, kind of like salesforce gives in terms of capability of creating entities, extending their entities and allowing you to build your own forms without writing any code.

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_form_builders

Comment: these seem more like developer tools, im looking for something that gives the power to the user of the app to build forms and entities, kind of like salesforce gives in terms of capability of creating entities, extending their entities and allowing you to build your own forms without writing any code.

Comment: That sounds more like a complete app than a gem :)

Comment: In a few of my apps I use this functionality and am using `pg:hstore` (PostgreSQL extension) to store dynamic fields/questions. It works pretty well. Not abstracted into a gem though, although there are probably plenty around

Comment: [FormStack](http://www.formstack.com/) and [wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com/) both offer the functionality, but you'd have to check with them how/whether you can offer their service to your own users.

Comment: Yes, these are exactly the kind of thing, but dont want a service, want a gem/plugin that offers a good start on this sort of thing.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to combine yossarian's suggestion of dynamic fields/questions with a JS interface like [angularJS](http://angularjs.org/).  I can't think of or find anything which does this out of the box.